# PHP Static var not working

Tags: php, class, static

I'm working on a Captcha class and i'm almost done, there is one thing that doesn't work

In the file where I put the form, I start with this line:

```
    include 'captcha.php';
    $captcha = Captcha::tryCaptcha(2,4,'#000', '#ffffff');
```

and this is the captch construct:

```
static $do_generate = TRUE;
function __construct($aantal_letters = 2, $aantal_cijfers = 4, $voorgrond = '#000000', $achtergond = '#ffffff') {
    session_start();
    if (self::$do_generate == TRUE) {
        $letters = substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'),0 ,$aantal_letters);
        $cijfers = substr(str_shuffle('23456789'),0 ,$aantal_cijfers);
        $imgbreed = 18 * ($aantal_letters + $aantal_cijfers); 
        $_SESSION['imgbreed'] = $imgbreed;
        $_SESSION['captcha'] = $letters . $cijfers;
        $_SESSION['voorgrond'] = $this->hex2rgb($voorgrond);
        $_SESSION['achtergond'] = $this->hex2rgb($achtergond);
    }
}
```

so in other words I put my stuff in a session if the static var $do_generate ==  TRUE

So when I post the form, the captcha is getting checked by a procesor.php

like this:

```
if (Captcha::captcha_uitkomst() == TRUE) {
echo "Great";
} else {
echo "Wrong";
```

}

And this is the captcha function that checks the etered captcha code:

```
static function captcha_uitkomst() {
    if (strcmp($_SESSION['captcha'], strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['captcha-invoer']))) == 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        echo "test";
        self::$do_generate = FALSE;
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

If I enter a correct captcha code, it's all good, that works I get the echo great.
If wrong I get the echo Wrong,

Perfect, but.... when I go back to form (hit backspace one history back) to  enter a correct captcha, it regenerates a new captcha.

In the class: captcha_uitkomst you see that I made the self::do_generate FALSE
And the echo 'TEST' works when it's false, (just for checking)

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why do you think that captcha **shouldn't** regenerate when you click `back`?

Comment: Because the Image that's created by php with imagettftext, is not refresing, so it shows the old picture with a new generated code. That goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

When you hit "back", the page is reloaded. You get a new CAPTCHA.

The premise of your question is fundamentally flawed, as you have just randomly *assumed* that this shouldn't happen, whereas in reality this is **entirely by design.**

It wouldn't be a very effective CAPTCHA if you could repeatedly get it wrong then go back and try again; any bot could just start brute forcing it *and learning from the experience*.

Comment: Indeed it does, in the var dump I see that it regenerates, but I call the picture like this: <img src="image.php" /> and in image.php I create the picture from the captcha session, while the page gets reloaded, the picture somehow is not, if I hit F5, then the whole page is reloaded included the picture and the whole bunch is in sync.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: @RalphSchipper sounds like you're trying to say "the capcha image displayed is cached until I refresh the page" or some other such "it's the http cache headers in the `image.php` response" problem, especially in light of [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352160/php-static-var-not-working/24352459#comment37652660_24352160).

Comment: Yes @AD7six I totaly overlooked that it might be a chache issue, I'll take a look at that, if that works. I just want the displayed picture to be the same as the (regenerated) captcha key.